# Remote Assistance Tools from Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, remote-assistance

Are there any possible way to start the remote assistance tool from a windows 8 store app.

Would like to create a store app that I could install on my parents pc for starting the remote assistance tool and send me the file automatic. I have done this with a simple console application before but was wondering if there is any way to do so from a store app. That would enable me to get a nice tile with a picture of me and make the install process better also.

here is the code that do it from a console app without the send part.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        string fileurl = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "Invitation.msrcincident";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "Msra.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/saveasfile " + fileurl + " MyPassword";
        Console.WriteLine(p.StartInfo.Arguments);
        p.Start();

        while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        while (File.Exists(fileurl) == false)
        {


            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code from a Store app?

Comment: You cant invoke processes from store apps they are in a sandbox so is looking for alternative ways to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Install a non-store app as well that has a WCF endpoint.  You call the WCF endpoint from the store app and then the non-store app can spawn the process.

Comment: @JohnKoerner you don't necessairly need the overhead of WCF (and do you really want a service running 24/7?). Could some other form of IPC such as DCOM suffice?